# Consistency validation for sql server registry keys error on domain user

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to install MSSQL 2012 x64 standalone on clients computer which is in Domain Users group. Only `consistency validation for sql server registry keys` fails. When i open the event log it says `AclPermissionsFacet, The SQL server registry keys from a prior installation.`

-I am running the setup with Administrator credentials.
-It is a clean installation.

Answer (score 0):

I was installing it from external hard drive. I just copied the setup to the desktop. Problem solved.